# Attach xml file into pdf file generated through oracle apex

Tags: xml, pdf, apex

I'm using Oracle apex. in one of the process, I need to generate pdf file with xml attachment. creating pdf file is a simple process but I couldn't know how to attach xml file to it. any clue what should I do ?
thank you

Is there any tool I can you to attach the xml file ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I need a way to create PDF-a3 file from oracle apex. what apex does currently is creating normal pdf file without xml attachment.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how to do this in oracle apex? adding a command line before/after generating the pdf ?